# Pass variables from node.js server side controller to angular.js client side controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

in express.js when you will pass a value from controller to view, using jade (default in express) you set in controller:

```
response.render('templatename',{name:'Peter'});
```

so you can echo it on the view as:

```
#{name}
```

In Angular.js you put values you want to show in view to the $scope var,
    $scope.name = "Peter"
and echo it on the view as:
    {{name}}
So, maybe I can`t echo values from node.js directly to angular. then there is a way to echo values from node.js to an js file to be used as angular.js controller?

my target is pass values from node.js server side controllers to angular.js client side controllers

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to take a step back and spin through a MEAN tutorial (not necessarily the M part), AngularJS is designed to be a client-oriented framework, e.g., it makes a request to the back end, puts the appropriate values into `$scope`, and the display happens more or less automagically.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't so clear enough. But in Angularjs, you can pass in a scope in the controller and call it in your view template

```
//controller.js
$scope.name = "Your name";

//index.html
<div>{{name}}</div>
```

[Angular tutorials](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02)